# How to ignore .gitignore files in git status?

Tags: git, gitignore

When I run `git status`, it lists a bunch of `.gitignore` files that I am not interested in seeing in the list (they got updated locally by `Eclipse`).  I browsed numerous posts in regards to this seemingly common issue but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

E.g. I went into `~/.gitconfig` and found that

`excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global`

Then I went into that file and added `.gitignore` at the tail but that did not change anything.

How do I effectively ignore .gitignore files in git status so they don't clutter the view?

Comment: Does `git status` show the `.gitignore` files being tracked?  If so, then you can't ignore them.  Maybe move Eclipse's extra settings into `.git/info/exclude` and drop the changes to the `.gitignore` files.

Comment: i tried that, didn't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you might be misunderstanding what "ignore" means to Git. A file name mentioned in `.gitignore` means that if a file is *untracked*, then `git status` will not show that file as an untracked file.

Ignoring a file does *not* do anything when the file is tracked by Git, and has been modified. That is considered a change to your repository, which Git doesn't let you ignore. (After all, you have already told Git that file is important enough to store in your repository, so Git has an obligation to inform you about changes to that file.)

If your tools (Eclipse) is modifying your `.gitignore` files, I would suggest you instruct Eclipse to stop doing that.

Comment: So then.. how to ignore .gitignore if it it were in the repo?  This is a valid use case.

Comment: @javadba If you need to make local changes to `.gitignore` that you don't want to commit, then use `.git/info/exclude` instead.

Comment: @javadba Or use `git update-index --assume-unchanged myfile`. This is convenient when a file should be tracked but you never want to check in local changes to it.

Comment: @RadHaring and Greg - thanks for the tips.  These are useful wrt spark codebase.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
git status --ignored
```

From `man git-status`:

> --ignored
>       Show ignored files as well.

Comment: This seems to be an answer to the opposite of the problem the user is experiencing. `git status` is *showing* ignored files. He **doesn't** want to see them.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the entry '.gitignore' to the .gitignore file.Then 'git status' won't show .gitignore as one of the untracked files. This might be helpful if you don't want to include .gitignore in the source control.

Answer (score 0):

You can,

Git ignore is internally used to set the ignores.

you can t ignore the ignore setting files, this woule be a strange behaviour

Answer (score 0):

See if your version of git supports the untracked option.  For example:

**git status --untracked-files=no**